# JS Array passing value changes for no reason

Tags: javascript

I have a function which loops an array... whilst it works it seems to change the value of the information being sent from "begin" function to "process" function, but i don't know why... I'm sure i made a silly mistake but I cannot see the mistake =/

This is my function:

```
var array_data = data[9]; //global array to use
console.log(array_data); //debug

function process(i){
alert('Number is '+i); // shows the value "7" (should show value "1")
}

function begin(){
var count = 0;

for(i in array_data){

if(parseInt(array_data[i][9])){ //if true

    var result = create_layout(i); //function to make the layout
    alert('Number is '+i); //shows the value "1" (this is correct so far)

   document.getElementById('result'+count).innerHTML = result;  
   document.getElementById('result'+count).onclick = function() { process(i); };    

count++;

       }
}   

window.onload = function() {  
begin();  
};
```

Below is my array for (array_data) from the console log:

```
1: Array[10]
   0: "Car One"
   1: "1"
   2: "3"
   3: "d2.jpg"
   4: "1"
   5: "1"
   6: "200"
   7: "85"
   8: "5000"
   9: "1"
length: 10    

7: Array[10]
   0: "Car Two"
   1: "1"
   2: "1"
   3: "e2.jpg"
   4: "1"
   5: "0"
   6: "500"
   7: "50"
   8: "3000"
   9: "0"
length: 10
```

So I'm wondering why might it is changing the value of "i" when it reaches the process function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the time the `onclick` function actually gets called, the value of `i` will have changed because of the loop it's in. You should "anchor" its value. The easiest way to do it is like this:

```
for( some loop on `i`) {
    (function(i) {
        // your code that depends on `i`
    })(i);
}
```

This will ensure that the value of `i` will not change within that closure (unless you change it yourself)

Comment: Why would it change for that div though surely once its looped and assigned it to div ID result0 the next loop will assign it to div ID result1 ?

Comment: Yes, but the actual value of `i` changes. Functions aren't constants, they're closures and they inherit the variables of their containing scope. If those variable change in that scope, the function will reflect that change.

Comment: So setting div id="result0" to i with a value of "1" isn't set in stone in the browser as the number one but rather the variable i?

Comment: Pretty much. But by using the code I gave you, it basically means that `i` is no longer affected by the loop inside there.

Comment: ok yeh your method did fix the issue, though it looks a bit ugly with the (i); at the end =/

Comment: Put it another way, the code you had before used `i` at the time the onclick was called, not when the event handler was created.

Comment: Ah i see :) i'll have to remember that!

Answer (score 2):

- <s>Don't use [for-in-loops on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)</s> (OK, doesn't apply here)
- There's a missing closing brace for your `begin` function
- Just use `window.onload = begin;` - no need for an extra function
- Yet, there is need for a extra closure for your `i` variable. The time the event handler gets executed, it will use the variable `i` - whose current value is the one it got in the last loop cycle. It might be the same issue with your `count` variable.

```
for(var i=0; i<array_data.length; i++) (function(i){

    <...>.onclick = function() { ...i...; };    

})(i);
```

Comment: May i ask why the for in loop is not recommended also as i need to assign I to the key ID rather than the position.

Comment: Um, is `array_data` no array?

Comment: It is an array from a json_encode i carry the id related to the data in the array as the key number rather than 0 1 2 3 etc if that makes sense? But its still only an array.length of 2

Thats why in the console.log it shows 1 then 7, those are the row id's in MYSQL table !

Comment: Could you print the JSON representation in your question? There's a differencs between arrays (lists) and objects (dictionaries/maps/...) in javascript. An Array of length 2 can only have the keys/indizes 0 and 1.

Comment: That's not JSON. Is it `{"1":...,"7":...}` or `[...,...]`?

Comment: Good - the name was confusing.

Answer (score 0):

In ECMAScript 5, you can go ahead and use `bind` to bind the argument to your function:

```
document.getElementById('result' + count).onclick = process.bind(null, i);
```

This is great if you don't have to worry about Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.